# is this bash statement taking input from /dev/null?

Tags: python, bash, shell, redirect

Is this bash statement taking input from /dev/null ?

```
nohup python ./deepdream.py h> out.log 2> err.log < /dev/null &
```

what I think I see is a python script with a parameter of 'h' passed to it.  the standard output is redirected to out.log and the error output is redirected to err.log.

It looks like it is taking input from /dev/null but that doesnt make any sense to me.

then the entire command is backgrounded.

Where am I geting off track.  TIA

Comment: Taking input from /dev/null is not unusual if you want to make sure that your program doesn't actually read anything.

Comment: If wikipedia is to believed, it's to [avoid hanging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup#Overcoming_hanging)

Comment: I think err.log < /dev/null is used in this example to ensure err.log is created or rewritten even if python ./deepdream.py produces no stderr output.